What is "that movie" in SNC: Movie Melody
This might not be the right site for this, but I know it doesn't belong on programming for U&L. 
You can see/hear the song here for reference (I have no way to tell if it's the offical video or not): 


Starting at around 3:14, there are the lyrics:

Have you seen this movie?
  Our guess would be no,
  But this famous theme song
  You probably know
  We'll show you how this song is used
  In movies and shows (Your favorite shows)
  The character's always in a race
  Running in slow-mo  

I know it's picking on the trope, but what is the movie that started it all. The lyrics make is sound like some horrid 80's B movie, but I have seen a lot of those, and I don't remember them having that trope.  

They're parodying Chariots of Fire from 1981 (specifically this scene). Usually IDing just a video is off-topic, but at least you included more details.

Thanks, but there is a tag for IDing movies.

And they are sated as on topic so long as you have enough details to actually ID the movie. http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Identify-This-X Questions

"there is a tag for IDing movies" I know, I'm somewhat familiar with that tag. ;) But IDing a film just from a clip is usually off-topic. However, I agree that you provided plenty of other details, so I posted the answer.

This is a parody (or rather a parody of the parodies) of the famous opening scene of Chariots of Fire, the 1981 British historical drama about two athletes in the 1924 Olympics, which is accompanied by Vangelis' theme of the same name. The slo-mo scene was quoted & parodied many times. Here it is:



